# Is there a way to access avro data stored in hbase using hive to do analysis

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hbase, avro

My Hbase table has rows that contain both serialized avro (put there using havrobase) and string data. I know that Hive table can be mapped to avro data stored in hdfs to do data analysis but I was wondering if anyone has tried to map hive to hbase table(s) that contains avro data. Basically I need to be able to query both avro and non avro data stored in Hbase, do some analysis and store the result in a different hbase table. I need the capability to do this as a batch job as well. I don't want to write a JAVA MapReduce job to do this because we have constantly changing configurations and we need to use a scripted approach. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can write an HBase co-processor to expose the avro record as regular HBase qualifiers. You can see an implementation of that in [Intel's panthera-dot](https://github.com/intel-hadoop/project-panthera-dot)